# How to access localhost with VPN turned on

Tags: reactjs, macos, localhost, vpn, liveserver

I work on a mac OS with VPN enabled. It blocks access to localhost. So when I run a live server or a React application, I get an error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
Please avoid the advice like disabling the VPN. I'm asking for an explanation if somehow on mac os and using NordVPN I can add localhost to exceptions and allow access.
Thank you very much for the answers.

Running live server or React app gives error in browser ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding. Localhost refer to YOUR computer and having an active VPN does not change that.

Maybe your react app try to access ressources that aren't local